# gitea using a normal user and https

Tags: ssl, https, iptables, gitea

I am trying to setup gitea to use https with a certificate I got from letsencrypt running the service as a **normal user**.

I already got it working with http on port 80 with a normal user `git` and redirecting port 80 to port 3000 using iptables.

Also I already got it working with https on port 3000 redirecting to port 3080.

But I can't figure out how to configure it (maybe along with iptables) so that requests to port 80 redirect to the appropiate port (3000? 3080?).

I redirect the port 80 to port 3000 using this iptables command as root:

`# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000`

And this is the relevant part of my configuration for HTTP

```
RUN_USER         = git

LOCAL_ROOT_URL   = http://localhost:3000/
DOMAIN           = example
HTTP_PORT        = 80
ROOT_URL         = http://example.com
```

This is my configuration for HTTP on port 3000 redirecting to port 3080

```
RUN_USER            = git

PROTOCOL            = https
LOCAL_ROOT_URL      = https://localhost:3000/
DOMAIN              = example.com
HTTP_PORT           = 3000
REDIRECT_OTHER_PORT = true
PORT_TO_REDIRECT    = 3080
ROOT_URL            = https://example.com
CERT_FILE           = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
KEY_FILE            = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
```

With this configuration I can visit `https://example.com:3000` and it works fine but if I visit `https://example.com:3080` I get an `Secure Connection Failed` with `Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG`.

I tried to redirect the port 80 to port 3080 using iptables but it didn't work.

Can you help me set it up so I can run the service as normal user in port 80 so that people can visit it at `https://example.com` ? (maybe using iptables as root beforehand to redirect some ports) Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port for HTTPS is 443. Most people would solve this by using a reverse proxy, not iptables.

Gitea can handle letsencrypt itself. Here's how:

```
[server]
PROTOCOL=https
DOMAIN=git.example.com
ENABLE_LETSENCRYPT=true
LETSENCRYPT_ACCEPTTOS=true
LETSENCRYPT_DIRECTORY=https
LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=email@example.com
```

Taken from: https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/https-setup/

Comment: that requires the normal user to be able to open port 80, the point of my question is about not having to run the service as root

Comment: `setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /path/to/binary/gitea`

Answer (score 3):

In case someone else need it here is the final configuration file is this, it redirects http requests to https.

I used `# setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep /path/to/binary/gitea` as ptman suggested.

```
RUN_USER            = git

[server]
PROTOCOL            = https
DOMAIN              = example.com
HTTP_PORT           = 443
REDIRECT_OTHER_PORT = true
CERT_FILE           = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
KEY_FILE            = /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
SSH_DOMAIN          = example.com
DISABLE_SSH         = false
SSH_PORT            = 22
OFFLINE_MODE        = false
```

Answer (score 2):

The letsencrypt api is included in gitea. To setup gitea with docker-compose and let's encrypt just edit your [server] configuration like this:

```
....
[server]
APP_DATA_PATH    = /data/gitea
DOMAIN           = example.com
SSH_DOMAIN       = example.com
HTTP_PORT        = 443
ROOT_URL         = http://example.com
PROTOCOL=https
ENABLE_LETSENCRYPT=true
LETSENCRYPT_ACCEPTTOS=true
LETSENCRYPT_DIRECTORY=https
LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=info@foo.com
.....
```

and your docker-compose.yaml port configuration will look like this:

```
  server:
    image: gitea/gitea:1.13.2
    container_name: gitea
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "222:22"
....
```